# How to generate consolidated swagger documentation for multiple Azure function apps(v3) projects present in single solution

Tags: .net-core, swagger, azure-functions, swagger-ui, azure-function-app

I have C#.net (.net core) visual studio solution structure as follows:
[image]

I want to generate swagger documentation and execute azure functions using 'Try it out' option.
Is it possible to combine and show all functions(1,2,3,4) from different projects available in a single swagger page? If yes, how to do that? I need to plugin swashbuckle in an existing developed function apps. Please guide here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to do that its use FunctionMonkey for Azure Functions. https://functionmonkey.azurefromthetrenches.com/guides/http/swagger.html

But the best way its uses APIM OpenAPI definitions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-openapi-definition

Comment: Thanks Anton. If we want to customize APIM then the documentation has to be developed as a separate app and has to be hosted. So we have decided to not use APIM. The project needs specifically swagger / APIM,  so the FunctionMonkey is not an option right now. I'll explore FunctionMonkey though. Could you please help me with Swagger?

Comment: FunctionMonkey absolutely independent from APIM.. FM and APIM its just two different options to provide OpenAPI